# Fetching data from API in react native using redux

Tags: react-native, redux

I am working on a react-native project where I am trying to fetch data from an api using axios library and display the data.So,my app first shows a splash screen and it then needs to navigate to a page which consists of tabs.The tabs will contain the data from the api.

So,I am trying to initialize my store in my Homepage which comes after the splash screen.I have my reducer and action defined separately in 2 different files.

**App.js file**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import SplashScreen from './src/components/SplashScreen';
import HomeScreen from './src/components/HomeScreen';

const Navigation = StackNavigator({
    Splash: {
      screen: SplashScreen
    },
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen
    }
})

export default Navigation;
```

**My SplashScreen component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet,
         Text,
         View,
         } from 'react-native';

export default class SplashScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
    },2000)
  }

  render() {
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.welcome}>Splash Screen</Text>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'skyblue'
  },
  welcome: {
    color: '#FFF',
    fontSize: 30
  }
})
```

My HomeScreen component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet,
         Text,
         View,
         } from 'react-native';

export default class SplashScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
    },2000)
  }

  render() {
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.welcome}>Splash Screen</Text>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'skyblue'
  },
  welcome: {
    color: '#FFF',
    fontSize: 30
  }
})




import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet,
         Text,
         View,
         } from 'react-native';

export default class SplashScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
    },2000)
  }

  render() {
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.welcome}>Splash Screen</Text>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'skyblue'
  },
  welcome: {
    color: '#FFF',
    fontSize: 30
  }
})
```

**Action.js file**

```
import axios from 'axios';
export const FETCH_DATA = 'fetch_data';

const API = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/fz62x';

export function fetchData() {
  const request = axios.get(API);

  return dispatch => {
    return request.then((data) => {
        dispatch({
          type: FETCH_DATA,
          payload: data
        })
    })
  }
}
```

**My reducer**

```
import { FETCH_DATA } from './actions';

export default function(state={}, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case FETCH_DATA:
      return {
        ...state,
        action.payload
      };

    default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

Can anyon please tell me if this the correct way? If not, then what is the correct way?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I would say there is no correct or incorrect way to do this. But I can share kind of a pattern that I usually use.

First I would create separate folders for different files. Actions in actions folder, reducers in reducers folder etc... I would create separate `constants.js` file and `configureStore.js` file and put them inside the project root directory.

I would drop Axios library and would just use `Fetch API` for data fetching. Considering your code I would do the following.

Create `configureStore.js` file inside your project `root` directory. I recommend you to use `Redux-Thunk`. You can find more info from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk).

**configureStore.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import app from './reducers';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

export default function configureStore() {
    let store = createStore(app, applyMiddleware(thunk))
    return store
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import configureStore from './configureStore';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';

const NavigationApp = StackNavigator({
    HomeScreen: { screen: HomeScreen }
})

const store = configureStore()

export default class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <NavigationApp />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

Let's create `constants.js` and we place it inside the project `root` directory.

**constants.js**

```
export const FETCHING_TODOS = 'FETCHING_TODOS';
export const FETCH_TODOS_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_TODOS_SUCCESS';
export const FETCH_TODOS_FAILURE = 'FETCH_TODOS_FAILURE';
```

Now let's move on and create our action file which would be put inside the `actions` folder. Let's name it something like `fetchToDos.js`. Let's create a simple function using `Fetch API`.

**fetchToDos.js**

```
import { FETCH_TODOS_SUCCESS, FETCH_TODOS_FAILURE, FETCHING_TODOS } from '../constants';

export function fetchToDos() {

    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(getTodos())

        return(fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/fz62x'))
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {

            return(dispatch(getToDosSuccess(json)))
        })
        .catch(err => dispatch(getToDosFailure(err)))
    }
}

function getToDos() {

    return {
        type: FETCHING_TODOS
    }
}

function getToDosSuccess(data) {

    return {
        type: FETCH_TODOS_SUCCESS,
        data
    }
}

function getToDosFailure() {
    return {
        type: FETCH_TODOS_FAILURE
    }
}
```

**fetchToDos.js with Axios**

```
import { FETCH_TODOS_SUCCESS, FETCH_TODOS_FAILURE, FETCHING_TODOS } from '../constants';
import axios from 'axios';

export function fetchToDos() {

    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(getUser())
        axios.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/fz62x')
            .then(function (response) {

                // handle your response here, create an object/array/array of objects etc... 
                // and return it in dispatch(getToDosSuccess(data over here))

                return(dispatch(getToDosSuccess(response.data)))
            })
            .catch(err => dispatch(getToDosFailure(err)))
    }
}

// rest is the same...
```

Moving on to reducers. Let's create two files - `index.js`, `todos.js` and put them inside `reducers` folder.

**todos.js**

```
import { FETCH_TODOS_SUCCESS, FETCH_TODOS_FAILURE, FETCHING_TODOS } from '../constants';

const initialState = {
    todos: [],
    isFetching: false,
    error: false
}

export default function todosReducer(state = initialState, action) {

    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCHING_TODOS:
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: true
            }
        case FETCH_TODOS_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: false,
                todos: action.data
            }
        case FETCH_TODOS_FAILURE:
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: false,
                error: true
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

**index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import todos from './todos';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    todos
})

export default rootReducer
```

Basically "heavy lifting" is done. I would only create one screen because let's assume that users would tap back button (Android) while at home screen, they would end up on that splash screen. So in this example I am going to use one screen only.

**HomeScreen.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    ActivityIndicator
} from 'react-native';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchTodos } from '../actions/fetchTodos';

class HomeScreen extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {

        this.props.fetchTodos()

    }

    render() {

        const { todos, isFetching } = this.props.todos

        if (isFetching) {
            return(
                <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                    <ActivityIndicator size={'large'} /> 
                </View>
            )
        } else {
            return(
                <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                    <Text>todos.length</Text>
                </View>
            )
        }

    }

}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        todos: state.todos
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        ...bindActionCreators({ fetchTodos }, dispatch)
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeScreen)
```

I really hope that you find this concept useful because I can say from my experience that it helped me a lot when I first get started and it helped me to understand the whole concept of redux much better.

Sorry if there are any typos and errors. I was on a flow.

Comment: If you don't mind, can I ask you one question.So,if I want to use axios for my data fetching, then what changes would be required.Actually, I am little bit confused with the action's fetchToDo.js file that you mentioned.i mean,I just want to simple get the results from the api using axios library.Sorry,I am very new to redux,so this gets very confusing for me.If you don't mind, can you please sow me how to write a simple actions file with axios library which will just fetch data from the api?

Comment: @pranami I created a data fetching method using Axios, it is very-very similar to Fetch API.

Comment: Would you suggest that we can avoid this "dispatch to service from screen and then do the work in the reducer" path in a scenario when I don't want data to persist in the store?

Comment: @Neo Yeah, absolutely. Whatever fits your needs.

Comment: Please anyone can tell me how can I pass parameter to `fetchTodos` action ?

Comment: @IvaloPajumets can you share a github repo link for this ? I am new to redux. Why prefer redux thunk over redux?

Comment: I think it's just a typo: `const { todos, isFetching } = this.props.todos` --> `const { todos, isFetching } = this.props`